# The appropriateness of an example regarding closure on the MDN docs

Tags: javascript, closures

On the [MDN topic for closures,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) they present this example as a "real world" application.

```
    body {
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    h2 {
      font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    function makeSizer(size) {
      return function() {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
      };
    }

    var size12 = makeSizer(12);
    var size14 = makeSizer(14);
    var size16 = makeSizer(16);


document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = size12;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = size14;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = size16;

<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
<a href="#" id="size-16">16</a>
```

My question is: would it not have been simpler to eliminate the closure altogether and assign the sizes directly as in document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = 12;? (thus rendering this a bad example?) The way it is done here seems very rube-goldberg-like.

Expanding further, I feel that a more salient example would be to keep the closure, but have the document element retrieve the text size directly from the id of the element, so we need only have a single statement as opposed to three (one for each text size). I'm not sure how it could be implemented but perhaps something like

document.getElementById(*some function here to listen for click and register id of element clicked*).onclick = makeSizer(*some regex to parse the id for the text size*)

Is this at all possible? if so is this considered best practice?

Comment: It's a minimal example. Sure they could give you a real world example where the handler is very large and therefore benefits more from this approach in order to avoid the repetition of code, but this example gets the point across. And yes, they could parse the number out from the ID. But that isn't always possible.

Comment: ...and I don't see anywhere on that page where the examples are called "real world". They're simple, practical examples. The important thing is to understand the approach so that you know how to do it when confronted with a particular situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: would it not have been simpler to eliminate the closure altogether and assign the sizes directly as in `document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = 12;`?

Not exacly. You would have to repeat yourself:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function () {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '12px';
};
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = function () {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '14px';
};
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = function () {
    document.body.style.fontSize = '16px';
};
```

So first let's make a function that's independent of the arguments...

```
var resize = function (size) {
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
};
```

but with this alone you don't improve very much:

```
document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function () {
    resize(12);
};
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = function () {
    resize(14);
};
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = function () {
    resize(16);
};
```

The closure allows you to keep the single implementation while also keeping the context for individual function calls (in this case "invocations of the event handler"):

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    return function () {
        document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    };
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(12);
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = makeSizer(14);
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = makeSizer(16);
```

The point of the example is is that you can assign a complete function *with arguments* when you use a closure.

---

> [...] have the document element retrieve the text size directly from the id of the element, [...]

Sure, that would have been possible, but then you don't need a closure anymore because the function can figure out context by itself:

```
var resize = function () {
    var size = this.id.split('-').pop();
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
};

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = resize;
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = resize;
document.getElementById('size-16').onclick = resize;
```